# Console.log() doesn't show DOM element as Object?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

I have this on my .js file:

```
let Odiv=document.getElementById("div0");
console.log(Odiv);
```

And the output is

```
<div id="div0">"something"</div>
```

When I'm expecting it to show the DOM element properties.
I'm using Chrome.
What's happening?

```js
let Odiv = document.getElementById("div0");
console.log(Odiv);
```

```html
<div id="div0">"something"</div>
```

Comment: Use `console.dir()`.

Comment: "What's happening?" Your expectations are incorrect.

Comment: console.log works in the console. SO's console looks different

Comment: @mplungjan No it doesn't. It shows the DOM tree rather than the properties.

Comment: @mplungian [`console.dir` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir). Namely, "displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object."

Comment: @HereticMonkey Then why sometimes when I refresh the page it shows the DOM object  with console.log()?.

Comment: See "Difference between log() and dir()" at [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! That is a useful answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you're seeing inconsistent behavior with a specific browser's implementation of `console.log`, that sounds like something you should take up with the browser maker.

Comment: @Barmar console.log AND console.dir BOTH show domElement.toString() in stack snippets. Either will show some kind of tree in the actual console. From OP's question it seems obvious he meant here or some other rendering OTHER than the browser console

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think it's obvious at all what the OP meant ("I have this on my .js file" being the most telling). If the OP meant in the snippet, please [edit] the question to make that clear. At that point, the question should probably be migrated to Meta Stack Overflow, since it's about the functioning of Stack Snippets, whose code has not been updated for a long, long time despite canon's having updated the source code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree it was not obvious, but as .dir and log does not show tags in the console, something else was going on

Comment: @mplungjan The question wasn't about stack snippets, it was about the real Chrome console. You added the stack snippet.

Comment: @HereticMonkey There was no stack snippet in the original question, it was added by mplungian in an edit.

Comment: @mplungjan The `console.log(Odiv)` shows the tag as described in the OP in Chrome Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) on my Windows 10 box. There's no tree because there are no child elements under the `div` provided (yes there are nodes, but no elements). `console.dir(Odiv)` shows a tree of properties, under `div#div0`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey oh. I am on OS X right now